50 students and 10 problems
$50$ students take $10$ problems. Each problem is solved by exactly $35$ students. Show that there are $2$ students who, combined, solved all of the $10$ problems.
Attempt: I know that there should be a pingenhole principle application.

What would your starting point be? Do you know what a graph in combinatorics  is?

Is it possible that there does not exist any person who solved each of Problem-8, Problem-9, and Problem-10?

"Show that there are at 2 students"... at least or most? Kindly edit your question

@AtharvJain I agree that our numerically named poster should clarify that in this post but we know that it must be "at least 2" because we could have the case that exactly $35$ students aced the test and the other $15$ solved none of the problems.

@JohnDouma It should be "at most 2 students". For the case of "at least 2 students", then just take all 50 students and we are done. $\quad$ It is true that in the worst case scenario, we do need at least 2 students. However, 2 students is also sufficient.

@CalvinLin We don't get to choose the outcome of the test. If we are claiming that at most $2$ students together got all ten questions right, then $35$ students acing the test would be a counter example.

@JohnDouma You're not interpreting the statement correctly (though I can see how you arrived at that interpretation). Does this rephrasing help: Show that we can find 1 or 2 students, who combined solved all of the 10 problems.

@CalvinLin I am not getting that. The problem says each problem was solved by exactly $35$ students. I interpret that as problem $1$ was solved by $35$ students, problem $2$ was solved by $35$ students, etc. Therefore, if $35$ students aced the test and $15$ students solved none of the problems, then $35$ students together solved all problems. Why is that wrong? When you say "at most", are you saying that there is no way that three students solved all ten problems?

@JohnDouma In that case, we can still "find 1 student who solved all of the 10 problems". Granted, we can do that 35 times. $\quad$ Your interpretation is "Consider all sets of students who combined solved 10 problems. Show that the minimum size is at least 2".  My interpretation is "Consider all sets of students who combined solved 10 problems. Show that there is a set of size at most 2." Do you see the difference?

@CalvinLin I see the difference. You are saying that we can find two students,e.g.  Alice and Bill, such that Alice may have solved problems $1-5$ and Bill solved $6-10$ and that that set is all we need to cover all ten problems. I don't see how you  get that interpretation from the original question.

By the pigeonhole principle, we know that there exists a person who solved at least $\lceil\frac{35 * 10}{50}\rceil = 7$ problems, let him be $v$.
if he didn't solve 3 problems we know that there are 50 students, and each of these problems is solved by 35 students, we know $v$ didn't solve them, by the pigeonhole principle we know there exists a student who solved at least $\lceil \frac{3 * 35}{49} \rceil = 3$ of them, let him be $u$.
if there were 2 problems he didn't solve, there would be a person $u$ who solved at least $\lceil \frac{2 * 35}{49} \rceil = 2$.
if there was 1 problem he didn't solve, a similar argument applies since $\lceil \frac{35}{49} \rceil = 1$.
if he solved all of the problems, let $u$ be anyone.
pair $u, v$ is a valid answer.

This form of pigeonhole principle where there exists a hole with at least $\lceil \frac{m}{n} \rceil$ pigeons is referred to as Generalized Pigeonhole principal in my country, If you need further help understanding it, Let me know

As an aside, you could have combined into one case, by picking the first 7 problems that $v$ solved, leaving 3 problems that $v$ may or may not have solved. That tweaks the PGP calculation to $ \lceil \frac{3 \cdot 35 } { 50 } \rceil  = 3$.
